# Mysql deadlock single insert transactions

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock, sql-insert

In the following case I am seeing a `deadlock detected, retry transaction` error:

Multiple insertions are occurring concurrently. Each insertion is done within a transaction for only a single row. (Each transaction only does one insert between its begin and commit.) The table has 3 columns, one of which is the PK. The PK is not auto-incremented.

How is it possible for a deadlock to occur if each transaction is only holding a single lock? I thought that a single row insertion would only require a single row level lock.

Comment: Did you try running `SHOW INNODB STATUS` to get some more info?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using on mysql shell: `show processlist` This will give you details of what queries are under execution among other things. This would be a good starting point.